# How do I call a post actionresponse passing the selected dropdown item as a parameter from javascript within a view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I call a post actionresponse passing the selected dropdown item as a parameter from javascript within a view within asp.net, razor, mvc

Basically, as I'm sure you can tell from the below code, I'm trying to accomplish the above without much success. What should I change to be successful? Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#mydropdown").change(function() {
        var selectedItem = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("DoStuff", "MainController")',
            type: "Post",
            data: { name: selectedItem },
            success: function () {
                alert('success');
            }
        });

    });
});
```

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DoStuff(String Selecteditem)
    {
        CIModel CIModellList = CILHelper.ImportFunc(Selecteditem);
        return View(CIModellList);
    }
```

As of now, nothing happens whem the dropdown is changed. Although if I remove the ajax function, and replace this with an alert. Then the alert in this case does appear.

**At this point, both the actionresult and the controller appear as though they do not exist (red) within the project even though both do and are named as stated.**

The c# seems to suggest neither the action or the controller actually exist, giving the errors "cannot resolve action" or "cannot resolve controller"

Comment: Are you sure "nothing happens", your `$.ajax` call doesn't have a failure callback so you would need to be debugging to sees if it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <select id="mydropdown">
        <option  value="a">a</option>
        <option  value="b">b</option>
        <option  value="c">c</option>
        <option  value="d">d</option>
    </select>



        <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
          $("#mydropdown").change(function() {
              var selectedItem = $(this).val();
              $.ajax({
                  url: '@Url.Action("DoStuff", "MainController")',
                  type: "Post",
                  data: { name: selectedItem },
                  success: function () {
                      alert('success');
                  }
              });

          });
      });
    </script>

</body>
</html>






    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DoStuff(string name)
    {
    CIModel CIModellList = CILHelper.ImportFunc(name);
    return View(CIModellList);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must change your name of the parameter to SelectedItem that matches the parameter your action method and stringify your json data before passing like,

```
JSON.stringify({ SelectedItem :selectedItem })
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451049/mvc5-controller-action-not-called-from-json-ajax-post/26451584#26451584) for reference.