# Pass a JS value to a model without reloading a View

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to pass a JavaScript value as a parameter to a Model without reloading the page? My goal is to change a dropdown based on what the user selected in an earlier dropdown. I tried:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(document).on('change', '#selectUserNames', function () {
            var selectedVal = $(this).val();
            var userClaims = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.GetUserClaims(selectedVal))); //////////PASSING VALUE HERE

            if (selectedVal == 'ABC@GMAIL.COM') {
                var html = '<option selected disabled>Select Claim:</option>';
                for (var i = 1; i < userClaims.length; ++i) {
                    html = html + '<option>' + userClaims[i] + '</option>';
                }
                $('#selectAuthPolicy').html(html);
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

I also thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465915/how-do-i-call-a-post-actionresponse-passing-the-selected-dropdown-item-as-a-para) might be useful, but I am trying not to reload the view (which I believe this will do)

Comment: `@Html.Raw()` is razor (server side) code. `selectedVal` is a javascript variable that does not even exist at that point. If you want to implement cascading dropdownlists, refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for how to code it correctly. Refer also [better way to load 2 dropdown in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420)

Comment: @StephenMuecke This is exactly what I needed, a little complicated, but Im trying to work through it now!