# MVC 4 - JQuery/Ajax post returns [ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: Category.]

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to post a form to a specific Action in MVC 4 using ajax. It enters the controller/action, but it throws a NullReferenceException, eventhough the Action does receive the data.

Here is the action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditPlayer(PlayerDisplay myPlayer)
    {    

            updatePlayer(myPlayer); //updatePlayer() does all the work of updating the player information.
            bool json = true;
            return Json(json);
    }
```

Here is the form

@model WebPlayerMonitor.Models.PlayerDisplay

```
<fieldset>
    <legend id="edit-player-account"><b>Account: </b>@Model.account</legend>
    <form id="editForm">
...
    <button id="btn-edit" class="button round medium">Save & Close</button>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</form>
</fieldset>
```

Here is the Ajax:

```
$("#btn-edit").click(function () {
 var myPlayer = $("#editForm").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/playermonitor/PlayerMonitor/EditPlayer",
        type: "Post",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: myPlayer,

        success: function (message) {
            $('#playermodal').foundation('reveal', 'close');
        },
        error: function (message) {
        }
    })
})
```

The Model:

```
    public class PlayerDisplay
    {
        [StringLength(maximumLength: 30)]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Account")]
        public string account { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [StringLength(maximumLength: 255)]
        [Display(Name = "Link Iovation")]
        public string link_Iovation { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Deposit Type")]
        public string Deposittype { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "8-Ball %")]
        public float? eight_Ball { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [StringLength(maximumLength: 50)]
        [Display(Name = "Location")]
        public string location { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Lifetime")]
        public float? lifetime { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Master")]
        public bool master { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [StringLength(maximumLength: 50)]
        public string Agent { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "B-Line")]
        public bool b_line { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [StringLength(maximumLength: 1020)]
        [Display(Name = "Notes")]
        public string notes { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [Required]

        public string Category { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Submitted")]
        public DateTime? date { get; set; }

        public string Office { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Submitted By")]
        public string User { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Updated By")]
        public string User_LastUp { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [StringLength(maximumLength: 200)]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Submit Notes")]
        public string shortNotes { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression(@"\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b",
            ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid IP format.")]
        [Display(Name = "IP Address")]
        public string ip_Address { get; set; }

        public bool? state { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Monitor Date")]
        public DateTime? monitorDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "RFCheck Date")]
        public DateTime? RFCheckDate { get; set; }

        public string categoryMultiple { get; set; }

        public PlayerDisplay()
        {
        }
    }
```

The Headers Info from Chrome Developer Tools:

```
Remote Address:xx.0.222.114:48
Request URL:http://crislife.im.priv:48/playermonitor/PlayerMonitor/EditPlayer
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:599
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=h40g5ar5yhrfgfsv4re1l0a1
Host:crislife.im.priv:48
Origin:http://crislife.im.priv:48
Referer:http://crislife.im.priv:48/playermonitor/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
Category=8Ball+Edge&Status=Ready+for+Check&Deposittype=Money+Bookers&Office=BETCRIS+INT+BKR&Agent=my+agentsssd&master=true&link_Iovation=soelinkssssss&eight_Ball=1&location=earthssssss&lifetime=2&ip_Address=123.123.123.125&b_line=true&notes=awesome+new+notesssssss5s&account=NEWAWESOME&state=True&monitorDate=9%2F24%2F2014+3%3A50%3A12+PM&shortNotes=quick%2Fnew+notes%2Fsome+more+notes%2Fandmorenotes%2Fjl%3Bjkl%3Bjasdf%2Fadding+to+it&RFCheckDate=9%2F24%2F2014+3%3A50%3A12+PM&date=9%2F22%2F2014+9%3A33%3A01+AM&User=ADEN&User_LastUp=ADEN&categoryMultiple=8Ball+Edge%2CFraud+Check%2CNew+Deposit%2CSharp
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:11536
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 20 Oct 2014 21:45:43 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

And the error I'm getting:

```
 [ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: Category.]   
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject() +745   
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth) +362   
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer) +115   
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit) +49   
System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +242   
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassc.<GetValueProvider>b__7(ValueProviderFactory factory) +28   
System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +248   
System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +165   
System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +536   
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +80   
System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +347   
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider() +66   
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +81   
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +153   
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +955  
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +146   
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +166   
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag) +27   
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +50   
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +146   
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +166   
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +497   
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +146   
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +166   
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag) +27   
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +409   
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +144   
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +146   
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +166   
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag) +27   
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +364   
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +12650919   
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

This ONLY happens when I publish it to the website. When I run it on debug mode, everything runs properly. Also, I have other ajax posts that are exactly the same, and those work no problem.
When I remove  contentType: "application/json" and dataType: 'json', I get a null reference exception. I've checked many times and it is capturing all the fields from the form.

Comment: you're missing the code that shows us what the javascript variable `myPlayer` is

Comment: Please see this [SO post][1] on the same kind of issue.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451049/mvc5-controller-action-not-called-from-json-ajax-post/26451584#26451584

Comment: Thanks ps2Goat, I missed adding that. I have added it now. Basically it's just a var myPlayer = $("#editForm").serialize();

Comment: And thanks for the link, Venkat. I've tried everything on that list with no luck. The thing is, my code runs smoothly on debug mode. It's when I publish it to the website that it gives me that error. I have multiple Actions and I call most, if not all, of them with Ajax, and they are coded pretty much the same way. All the other ones work.