# cannot call json result using jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

c# and jquery,

I have two drop-down lists(category and product), and have to change the product list based on the category.

```
  @Html.DropDownList("categoryId", new SelectList(ViewBag.Category, "Id", "Name"), "Select Parent Category", new { @class = "form-control categorydata" })      
  @Html.DropDownList("productId", new SelectList(ViewBag.Product, "Id", "Name"), "Select Product", new { @class = "form-control product-list" })
```

And i am writing the following controller for getting the products list.It is worked.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetProducts(int categoryId)
    {
        int tot = new Products().Total;
        int cont = 1;
        Category cat = new Category(2);
        var products = new Products(cont, tot, cat);
       // ViewBag.products = new Products(1,new Products().Total,new Category(categoryId));
        return Json(products);
    }
```

and my jquery is,

```
$('.categorydata').change(function () {
    var selCat = $(".categorydata").val();
    var url = "~/Add/GetProducts";   
    if (selCat.length != 0) {           
        $.get(url, { id: SelCat }, function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    }       
});
```

This jquery is didn't call the controller, and it can not get the data .

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Instead of `"~/Add/GetProducts"` Use `@Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller")` and Also instead of `$.get` use `$.getJSON`

Comment: You should set the `dataType` to json.

Comment: Don't you think `SelCat` should be `selCat` ??

Answer (score 1):

You should keep the property name in json data as same as the parameter name of the action method.

```
$.get(url, { categoryId : SelCat }, function (data) {
```

Refer the [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451049/mvc5-controller-action-not-called-from-json-ajax-post/26451584#26451584).

Answer (score 0):

You should use this.

`return Json(products,System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: but jquery never call the controller action

Comment: You used the HttpGet Attribute, so you should use JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet enum.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put dataType: 'json' in you ajax call: