# How to define URL in Javascript to call ActionResult methode which resides in a controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, crud

i have created web application in MVC using Entity Framework to perform CRUD operations. in when i Delete any record it takes me to Delete View and then i am able to Delete that Record. but instead of doing that i want to have a alert box stating "Are you sure you want to delete this record" through java script and then without talking user to another page i want to delete the record.

i am using following option but its not helping...

```
$(function () {
    $('table.dataList tbody a[linktype="Delete"]').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/DepartmentController/DeleteConformed/',
            dataType: 'script',
            success: function () {
                alert('Are you sure you want to Delete this Department');
            },
            error: function (req, status, err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        });
    });
```

It is caching error stating "Not Found". Am i doing any mistake while stating URL.

Comment: Please refer this SO post which may help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451049/mvc5-controller-action-not-called-from-json-ajax-post/26451584#26451584.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `success` callback is invoked *after* the request to the server has already been sent and the record already deleted.

You need to confirm the user intention *before* you're performing the Ajax request, typically using the `window.confirm` method.

Something like:

```
$('table.dataList tbody a[linktype="Delete"]').click(function (e) {
    if (!window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Department?"))
        return;

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/DepartmentController/DeleteConformed/',
        dataType: 'script',
        success: function () {
            alert('Department deleted successfully');
        },
        error: function (req, status, err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    });
});
```

See [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm)

Comment: can you please explain URL line. 
url: '/Department/DeleteConformed/'

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery dialog. In your View add:

```
<div id="confirm-dialog"></div>
```

and change your function:

```
$('table.dataList tbody a[linktype="Delete"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#confirm-dialog").dialog({
        title: "Are you sure you want to delete this Department?",
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 'auto',
        close: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    });

    $("#confirm-dialog").dialog({
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/DepartmentController/DeleteConformed/',
                    dataType: 'script',
                    success: function () {
                        alert('Are you sure you want to Delete this Department');
                    },
                    error: function (req, status, err) {
                        alert(err);
                    }
                });
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: When i click on Delete console give this notation: (...)dialog is not found. please explain.

Comment: do you add script with jquery dialog to your View head? Seems like this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Currenty what you're doing invokes the action method and only after that your confirmation dialog shows. I think you need the reverse. Assuming you have a button in your View that leads the user to the deletion of a certain record I would do this. First, I would have a function on the client side that would just ask user to confirm if he/she is  sure and set the button onclick to that function.

```
 function confirmDelete(){
    $('<div id="dialog">').dialog({
             text:"Are you sure you want to delete?",
             modal:true,
             buttons:[{
                text: 'Yes',
                click: yesDeleteIt()
                },
             {
                text: 'No',
                click: function ()
                {
                   $(this).dialog('close');
                }
             }]
       })
 }
```

And in your yesDeleteIt function you can go AJAX:

```
  function yesDeleteIt(){
     url= '/Department/DeleteConformed/';
     $.post(url);//
  }
```

Comment: Can you please Explain me how define URL. I mean url = '/controllername/actionname' is this right?

Comment: To say that it's correct 100% of the time would be to optimistic. But in typical, most cases yes, that's correct. If you want 100% working one, then you can type '@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")' inside the razor and send it as a parameter to the function.